How to use kerberos authentication in JDBC on Windows
I am trying to use Kerberos authentication in JDBC on Windows:
Java Version: Java 17
mssql-jdbc version: com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:12.6.1.jre11
I can login successfully in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio with Windows Authentication, but can not access database in my Java application, here is my java code:
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (
                Connection connection = 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;", "", "");
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select 'abc'")
        ){
            if(rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

After I run my application on this Windows machine, I got below error:
**java -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -jar kerberos-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar**

Java config name: null
LSA: Found Ticket
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found PrincipalName
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found EncryptionKey
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found TicketFlags
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found KerberosTime
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found String
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found Ticket constructor
LSA: Found PrincipalName constructor
LSA: Found EncryptionKey constructor
LSA: Found TicketFlags constructor
LSA: Found KerberosTime constructor
LSA: Finished OnLoad processing
Native config name: C:\Windows\krb5.ini
Loaded from native config
>>>KinitOptions cache name is C:\Users\<***>\<***>\<***>
>> Acquire default native Credentials
Using builtin default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 18 17 20 19.
LSA: Found KrbCreds constructor
LSA: Got handle to Kerberos package
LSA: Response size is 1843
LSA: TICKET SessionKey KeyType is 18
LSA: Valid etype found: 18
LSA: Principal domain is ***
LSA: Name type is 1
LSA: Name count is 1
LSA: Principal domain is ***
LSA: Name type is 2
LSA: Name count is 2
LSA: Session key all zero. Stop.
>>> Found no TGT's in native ccache
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Kerberos Login failed: Integrated authentication failed. ClientConnectionId:c6f18883-621c-4647-9369-adb0578b406a due to javax.security.auth.login.LoginException (Cannot get any of properties: [user, USER] from con properties not available to garner  authentication information  from the user)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.initAuthInit(KerbAuthentication.java:130)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.generateClientContext(KerbAuthentication.java:238)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:6587)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:5402)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:5334)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7739)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:4384)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3823)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:3348)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:3179)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1953)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1263)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
        at com.mssql.Kerberos.main(Kerberos.java:8)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Cannot get any of properties: [user, USER] from con properties not available to garner  authentication information  from the user
        at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForName(Krb5LoginModule.java:853)
        at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:689)
        at jdk.security.auth/com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:597)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:679)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:677)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:677)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.initAuthInit(KerbAuthentication.java:107)
        ... 22 more

Is there any configuration I am missing? Thanks,

Are you actually domain-joined?

Looks like that's using the Win2000-era "scrape tickets out of LSA" method (which isn't going to work on a modern system) instead of using SSPI directly... I see the OpenJDK source has both options implemented, but I can't figure out how to choose one or the other.
